# Why do we normalize images before CNN?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a question regarding normalization in CNN.
In general, we normalize images into either 0-1 or 0 mean with unit variance.
However, since batch normalization will do the normalization in the hidden layers, I can't really find a reason for the purpose of the normalization before the feeding into the model.
Can somebody explain the purpose of normalization before CNN?
Thank you!

Comment: CNN and NN in general performs better with normalized data.. It's like asking "Why do we need batch normalization in layer 1 if we are doing it in layer 2", same reason..